# Orthogonal Block Matrix, the relation between the block Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to find a relation between $U$ and $V$, such that U is a $(p\times d)$ semi-orthogonal matrix (i.e $\ U^{T}U=\mathbf{I}_{d}$) and $V$ is a $(p\times (p-d))$ matrix which is the completion of U. Such that, $\Gamma=[U \ ,\  V]$ is an orthogonal $(p\times p)$ matrix (i.e $\ U^{T}U=\mathbf{I}_{d}= \Gamma\Gamma^T$).

My working:

$\Gamma^T\Gamma =[U^T V^T]^T\ [U \ ,\ V]=\mathbf{I}_{p\times p}$

Therefore:

$\\\bigg[\begin{matrix}U^TU & U^TV\\V^TU &V^TV\end{matrix}\bigg]=\bigg[\begin{matrix}\mathbf{I}_{d\times d} & \mathbf{0}_{d\times p-d}\\\mathbf{0}^T_{d\times p-d} & \mathbf{I}_{p-d\times p-d} \end{matrix}\bigg]
$
Which implies that $U^TV=\mathbf{0}_{d\times p-d}$ and $V^TU=\mathbf{0}^T_{d\times p-d}$ and that V is also a semi-orthogonal matrix.

I also have the following equation in terms of U and V:
$\det(A)\det(U^T(A)^{-1}U)=\det(V^TAV)$ for any $p\times p$ symmetric matrix A.

My Working:

$\det(A)\det(U^T(A)^{-1}U)=\det(V^TAV)$

I am quite sure that there should be a relation but I cannot see it yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should point that all the matrices involved are non-zero

Comment: Why don't you use a basis in which $\Gamma$ (and so $U$ and $V$) are diagonal?

Comment: Did you figure this out? This formula would be useful for me. Do you have any more information?

Comment: I took a different approach in my work and I did not need this eventually. However, I was unable to find any additional relationships between these matrices.

Comment: Do you have a link to the derivation of this formula? Or can you cite where you found it? I'm curious. Thank you.